# Why is this call to mpi.scatter hanging?

Tags: python, mpi, mpi4py

I am just getting started with MPI. I have a sample code that is failing on a `mpi.scatter` call (it hangs on the 5-node case and i have to ctrl-c to exit).

My configuration follows:

- Raspberry Pi 3 (5 nodes)
- mpich-3.2
- mpi4py-1.3  (also tried mpi4py-2.0.0 with same result)
- python 2.7.9

After installing all of the above, the `hello-world` test from all nodes works fine as does the five-node `cpi` (calc pi) test. But the scatter test is failing with five nodes:

```
from mpi4py import MPI

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()
size = comm.Get_size()

data = None
if rank == 0:
   data = [1]    #... this is changed to ‘data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] for the 5-        node case
   print 'test 1: rank 0 data load', data
else:
    data = None

print 'entering scatter from rank: ', rank
data = comm.scatter(data, root=0)
assert data == (rank+1)**2
print 'rank: ', rank, ' scatter'

data += 1
print 'entering gather from rank: ', rank
data = comm.gather(data,root=0)
print 'rank: ', rank, ' gather'
```

The ONE-node case is runs and produces:

> pi@aor00:~/mpi4py $ mpirun.openmpi -np 1 -machinefile
>   /home/pi/mpi_testing/machinefile python
>   /home/pi/Desktop/sct/scattertest-1node.py
>
> test 1: rank 0 data load [1]
>
> entering scatter from rank:  0
>
> rank:  0    scatter
>
> entering gather from rank:  0
>
> rank:  0  gather
>
> but the FIVE-node run hangs and I abort it with ctrl-c
>
> pi@aor00:~/mpi4py $ mpirun.openmpi -np 5 -machinefile
>   /home/pi/mpi_testing/machinefile python
>   /home/pi/Desktop/sct/scattertest.py
>
> test 1: rank 0 data load [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>
> entering scatter from rank:  0
>
> entering scatter from rank:  2
>
> entering scatter from rank:  1
>
> entering scatter from rank:  4
>
> entering scatter from rank:  3
>
> ^Cmpirun.openmpi: killing job...

Comment: This sounds very much as a network problem. Make sure that each RPi could talk to every other over TCP. Also, make sure that there are no network interfaces with the same network address but not actually providing physical connectivity.

Comment: Hristo - thanks for the reply... i went through the ssh process of adding each node to the others lists of known hosts, then i ran a utility on each of the pi's (raspi-config) to enable console auto-login. I rebooted each node after both of the steps then checked the ability of each node to ssh to the others. all of those ssh commands work, except that each of the workers nodes attempt to ssh to the host node (node 0) requires a password. the tests continue to fail, so is that password requirement a problem for the scatter-gather communication? thanks. dgr

Comment: Not actually. Open MPI uses TCP directly for communication. SSH is only used while launching the processes initially. TCP communication could be prevented either by firewall rules or by having network interfaces in the same network but not actually providing connectivity. `iptables` and `ifconfig` are your friends in checking whether that's the case.

Comment: Hristo - thanks for the info... that was it... the Raspberry Pi 3 has wifi and bluetooth, so i blacklisted both on all five nodes... the code is now running as expected. thanks again for the suggestions. dgr